# How should I address a missing "Windows Search" registry key used to fix an Outlook indexing failure?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-registry

Outlook 2010 under Windows 7 exhibits Issue #5 Microsoft lists [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outlook-known-issues-in-the-June-2017-security-updates-3f6dbffd-8505-492d-b19f-b3b89369ed9b). The symptom is:

> When searching in Outlook, you get this error: “Something went wrong
>   and your search couldn’t be completed.”, or "Search results may be
>   incomplete because items are still being indexed".

The suggested workaround is:

```
Open Registry Editor.

Go to: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search

PreventIndexingOutlook

Set DWORD: 1
```

But there's no `Windows Search` key under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows` on my machine. (The key does exist in several other places in the registry, e.g., `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search`.)

Should I create a `Windows Search` key so that I can create a `PreventIndexingOutlook` underneath it?

Comment: Have you tried creating it?  Worth pointing out the key is only applicable   "Until the Windows Update fix release on 6/27" after that date the key won't do Anything

Comment: No. I'm asking if I should.

Comment: You should create it.  You can also wait until June 27th and the problem will fix itself.  If you don't feel comfortable creating the key then you shouldn't create the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's normal for subkeys of Policies to not exist until a value in them is set. The Group Policy setting "Prevent indexing Microsoft Outlook" (in the Windows Components → Search category) is the one that sets this value, and like all policies, configuring it will cause the Group Policy infrastructure to create the key if necessary so it can set the value. Since you're doing the same thing but manually, you will need to create the subkey first.